# Catching somebody else's exception

Tags: java, exception

We have a third party java code which is throwing a headless exception. Can we catch it in our code? The problem is how do we know which all third party code (which comes in a jar file) will throw the exception. We do not have the third party API docs.

Comment: Do you mean that it's literally throwing a [HeadlessException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html)?  I ask because it's a [RuntimeException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) which doesn't have to be declared.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely catch it in your code by wrapping these third party calls inside a `try`/`catch` block.

As far as knowing the exception type without documentation, that's tougher. Trial and error by printing out the exception type during development. Or develop in very tight `try`/`catch` blocks that catch an open `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

In an ideal scenario, you should stop using that third party API. Since you are already using it, it would be much better if you write wrappers around and use it.

- Construct an intermediate layer
- Define custom exceptions clearly
- Try analyzing the third party API main methods and see vulnerable points where you feel exceptions can arise
- Promptly throw them wherever possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you mean by a headless exception.

The challenge is that if you don't know what methods could have exceptions, you would have to catch every time you call that third-party API. You may want to have some abstraction layer over that API that merely delegates and wraps every call with a `try{call()} catch(Exception e){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `java.awt.HeadlessException`? According to the documentation:

> Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

Ofcourse you can try to catch it, but how it that going to help you? That third-party library probably won't be able to work on for example a server that doesn't have a keyboard, display or mouse.